# Show $\lim_\limits{x\to\infty} x(1-\frac{\ln (x -1)}{\ln x})=0$

Tags: calculus, limits

The following expression came up in a proof I was reading, where it is said "It is easily shown: $$\lim_{x\to\infty} x(1-\frac{\ln (x-1)}{\ln x})=0."$$

Unfortunately I'm not having an easy time showing it. I guess it should come down to showing that the ratio $\frac{\ln (x-1)}{\ln x}$ converges to 1 superlinearly, which seems intuitive but I don't know how to prove it formally. Any tips?

Edit: original question had an implicit typo - I had $\ln x - 1$ rather than the intended $\ln(x-1)$.

Comment: That's not right. $x(1-\frac{\ln x-1}{\ln x})=x(1-(1-\frac{1}{\ln x}))=\frac{x}{\ln x}\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: first of all, simplify limit. The use the L'Hopitals rule and you will get the right result(Your limit does not equal to zero)

Comment: Heed my warning, young pup: The path to the dark side starts with "it is easily shown"

Comment: Did you mean by chance $\ln(x-1)=\ln(x)+\ln(1-\frac1x)$ in the numerator?

Comment: @LutzL That's a good question and half the answer, both in one.

Comment: Yup, sorry - sloppy on my part. Needed parentheses, as LutzL guessed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question only makes sense if it was posed as
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}x\left(1-\frac{\ln(x-1)}{\ln x}\right)
$$
which can easily be transformed into
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{-x\ln(1-\frac1x)}{\ln x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1+O(\frac1x)}{\ln x}=0
$$

Comment: Your answer is the correct one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm still missing a piece conceptually. How do you get the asymptotics for $\ln(1-1/x)$ in the numerator?

Comment: This is the logarithm series, as in $-\ln(1-h)=h+\frac12h^2+\frac13h^3+…$ which converges and gives $-\ln(1-h)=h+O(h^2)$ for $|h|<1$.

Comment: Perhaps an easier way: substitute $x=\frac{1}{h}$ to obtain $\frac{\log(1-h)}{h \log(h)}$, and use L'Hopital.

Answer (score 7):

Well it's false :
$$x\biggl(1-\frac{\ln x-1}{\ln x}\biggr)=\frac x{\ln x}\to+\infty. $$